# angular js getting out variable from $http is service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have created a service which gets a json from a remote server, not I need to get the result and set it as a property of the service, but I don't know how to get the property out of the function

```
app.service('varService',['$http', function($http){
    var ip = myip;
    window.city = '';
    $http.get('http://ip-api.com/json/'+ip)
    .then(function(data) { window.city = data.data.city; });

    this.city=city;  
}]);
```

the property `this.city` doesn't receive any value , however when I do `console.log` inside `.then()` the value exists, how do I solve the problem, how do I get value out of `$http.then()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you can't get data return by ajax as soon as you execute that line of code, you should use `.then` callback to retrieve data over there. You could use `.then` over $http call to get data from ajax.

```
app.service('varService',['$http', function($http){
    var ip = myip;
    var self = this;
    self.getCity = function (){
       return $http.get('http://ip-api.com/json/'+ip)
       .then(function(data) { 
           self.city = data.data.city; 
           return self.city; //do return city retrieved  
       });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$http.get` returns a promise, when you assign the city value, the request hasn't actually returned from the web server yet.

You need to return the promise from your service and instead handle your `.then()` callback handler in your invoking controller.

```
app.service('varService',['$http', function($http){
    var ip = myip;
    this.getIp = $http.get('http://ip-api.com/json/'+ip);
}]);

// controller
varService.getIp.then(function(data) { window.city = data.data; });
```

This is the recommended approach by the [John Papa AngularJS Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y061) and it allows you to chain multiple promises together.

Comment: thanks, but the thing is that I share this.city between multiple controllers so l need it to be set inside the varService